# Java while loop until conditions are met

Tags: java

Trying to make the user keep inputting correct integers between 2 sets of values, but for example if the user inputs a wrong integer, then the while loop skips and runs onto the next code in my program. If anyone could point out how I can make the user repeat the question at each step if they get it wrong, would appreciate it.

```
System.out.print("How many asteroids: ");
    int asteroid = input.nextInt();
    while (asteroid > 0) {
        System.out.print("x location of the asteroid (between 1-950 pixels): ");
        double asteroidLocationX = input.nextDouble();
        if (asteroidLocationX >= 1 && asteroidLocationX <= 950) {
            System.out.print("y location of the asteroid (between 150-550 pixels): ");
            double asteroidLocationY = input.nextDouble();
            if (asteroidLocationY >= 150 && asteroidLocationY <= 550) {
                System.out.print("Width of the asteroid (min: 30 pixels, max: 50 pixels): ");
                double asteroidSizeWidth = input.nextDouble();
                if (asteroidSizeWidth >= 30 && asteroidSizeWidth <= 50) {
                    System.out.print("Height of the asteroid (min: 30 pixels, max: 50 pixels): ");
                    double asteroidSizeHeight = input.nextDouble();
                    if (asteroidSizeHeight >= 30 && asteroidSizeHeight <= 50) {
                        gc.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
                        gc.fillOval(asteroidLocationX, asteroidLocationY, asteroidSizeWidth, asteroidSizeHeight);
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again");
                } else
                    System.out.println("Wrong input, try again");
            }else
                System.out.println("Wrong input, try again");
        } else
            System.out.println("Wrong input, try again");
        asteroid--;
    }
```

Comment: One of the things you will find as you progress in learning programming is that this kind of question is very much tied to getting input from the console. On the screen there are ways (a) to filter input so incorrect values cannot be entered and (b) signal visually and through an error pane that a value isn't correct. Over the internet 4xx http response codes codes can be sent back to indicate bad input. So I'd advise you not to get to hung up on this problem

Comment: AND you should not encapsulate all those ifs. The loops have the continue statement, that interrupts the loop and continues it with the next state, like so: `if (asteroidLocationX < 1 && asteroidLocationX > 950) { System.out.println("Wrong input, try again"); continue;}  double asteroidLocationY = input.nextDouble(); if (asteroidLocationY < 150 && asteroidLocationY > 550) { System.out.println("Wrong input, try again"); continue; } ` etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-ask the question if there's a problem with the answer

```
double val = -1;
do {
  System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
  val = input.nextDouble();
while (input >= 1 && input <= 10);
```